# How to tackle r(1400) error?

Tags: stata

I'm estimating the demand for several food items using Almost Ideal Demand System. There, I have to do censoring using Multivariate Tobit model.

I used the following code & it returned an error as "initial values not feasible, r(1400)".

---

```
//homogeneity//
constraint define 1 [q1]lnp1+[q1]lnp2+[q1]lnp3=0
constraint define 2 [q2]lnp1+[q2]lnp2+[q2]lnp3=0


//symmetry//
constraint define 3  [q1]lnp2=[q2]lnp1



global demand1 "(q1: w1 lnp1 lnp2 lnp3 lnxp)"
global demand2 "(q2: w2 lnp1 lnp2 lnp3 lnxp)"



mvtobit $demand1 $demand2, const(1 2 3)
```

---

I don't know how to tackle it. Could anyone please help me to overcome this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are similar questions [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2010-08/msg01322.html) and [here](http://statalist.1588530.n2.nabble.com/st-xtmelogit-and-inital-values-not-feasible-r-1400-error-td3932880.html) which you may want to look into.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution from them. Anyway thank you for letting me aware of that forum.

Comment: This kind of problem seems to be tackled quite differently by most users. Type in Stata `http://www.stata-journal.com/software/sj12-3/st0268/quaids.sthlp` to learn about `quaids`.

Comment: Thank you sir. But, I'm using LA/AIDS. The error comes when I use mvtobit.